# error when trying to add a code to existing code

Tags: excel, vba

i have code below whereby it works like a charm however i have would like to add an extra control code and i get an error saying object required. i have added extra code for combobox7 whereby when combobox7 is selected depending of result needs to update the sheet.

```
Function IsComplete(ByVal Form As Object, ByVal sh As Object, ByRef RecordData() As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i           As Integer, a As Integer, ArrayCol As Integer
    Dim msg         As String
    Dim ControlName As Variant
    Dim IsRequired  As Boolean, IsValidDataType As Boolean
    Dim HasEntry    As Boolean

    On Error GoTo myerror
    
    ControlName = GetControls(Form)
    
    ReDim RecordData(1 To 1, 1 To 43)
    
    For i = LBound(ControlName, 1) To UBound(ControlName, 1)
        With Form.Controls(ControlName(i, 1))
            IsRequired = UCase(ControlName(i, 2)) = "YES"
            HasEntry = Len(.Text) > 0
            ArrayCol = ControlName(i, 7) - 1
            If HasEntry Then
                'validate selected data entry type
                Select Case ControlName(i, 3)
                
                    Case "Numeric"
                        'numeric only
                        IsValidDataType = IsNumeric(.Text)
                        RecordData(1, ArrayCol) = Val(.Value)
                        'date
                    Case "Date"
                        IsValidDataType = IsDate(.Text)
                        If IsValidDataType Then RecordData(1, ArrayCol) = DateValue(.Value)
                        'text (default)
                    Case "Text", ""
                        IsValidDataType = Len(.Text) > 0
                        RecordData(1, ArrayCol) = .Value
                        If IsValidDataType Then
                            Select Case i
                                Case 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 12
                                    RecordData(1, ArrayCol) = StrConv(RecordData(1, ArrayCol), vbProperCase)
                                Case 10
                                    RecordData(1, ArrayCol) = StrConv(RecordData(1, ArrayCol), vbUpperCase)
                                     Case 7
                                        RecordData(1, ArrayCol) = Environ("username")
                            End Select
                        End If
                        
                End Select
            
            End If
            
            If IsRequired And Not HasEntry Then
                msg = IIf(ControlName(i, 4) = 0, "Entry Required", ControlName(i, 4))
                MsgBox msg, 48, "Entry Required"
                .SetFocus
                Exit Function
            ElseIf HasEntry And Not IsValidDataType Then
                MsgBox "Invalid Data Type", 48, "Invalid Entry"
                .SetFocus: Exit Function
            Else
            End If
        End With
endloop:
    Next i
    
     If ComboBox7.Value = "No" Then
        End If

    If ComboBox7.Value = "Yes" Then
        TextBox37.Value = ""
        TextBox38.Value = ""
        End If

    IsComplete = True
    
myerror:
    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox (Error(Err))
End Function
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `Form.Controls("Combobox7")` etc. to refer the the combobox in the same way you are referring to the other controls on `Form` in the rest of the code?

Comment: Hi Norie i have tried your suggestion and come with an error "Object require"

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Hi @norie sorry it worked, i just placed the code in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Hi norie sorry it worked, `Form.Controls("Combobox7")`